# How to create infinite scroll in Vuetify autocomplete using backend?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, scroll, autocomplete, vuetify.js

How to check when the scroll is down in autocomplete? And then upload more results by method `initialize()`? Something like pagination but in autocomplete.

Template:

```
        <v-autocomplete
          :items="items"
          item-text="name"
          item-value="id"
          label="Item List"
        ></v-autocomplete>
```

Script:

```
  data: () => ({
    items: [],
    page: 1
  }),
 methods: {
    initialize() {
      return ItemService.getItems(this.page)
        .then((response) => {
           return response;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          this.handleError(error, this.errors);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: There are no built-in functionality in vuetify v-autocomplete. But possibly [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67813494/9275224) will help you to solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56492851/how-to-create-infinite-scroll-in-vuetify-autocomplete-component/67813494#67813494) and I have it:

```
<v-autocomplete>
      :items="items"
      item-text="name"
      item-value="id"
      label="Item List"
  <template v-slot:append-item>
    <div v-intersect="endIntersect" /> 
  </template>
</v-autocomplete>
```

```
    async endIntersect(isIntersecting) {
      if (isIntersecting) {
        this.page += 1;
        let moreItems = await this.initialize();
        this.items = [...this.items, ...moreItems];
      }
    }
```